# Cronin enhancement in p-A collisions

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics

What is the physical picture behind Cronin enhancement in proton-nucleus collisions at intermediate transverse momentum?

Comment: Perhaps [this PhD thesis](http://www.rmki.kfki.hu/~bgergely/bgg_summary_dr.pdf) can be of help?

Comment: I can turn this into an answer later, but I expect you will find plenty of theories but no well-accepted  full explanation. Every conference I go to, I see people trying to use their latest model to explain the Cronin effect, often with some success, so there isn't a unique model that fits it.